# BluetoothServerSocket: how to handle subsequent connections

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to develop an application that will allow devices to communicate from time to time (one device sends a simple message, another one sends a response).

This communication is not going to happen too often (once in several minutes), so it does not seem to be reasonable to keep a permanent connection between the devices. Besides, the connection may be lost for some reason, so I'm going to need a some sort of the recovery logic.

Instead, I'd prefer the app to establish a new connection each time it needs to send data to a peer. However, the specs say, that after `BluetoothServerSocket.accept` returns, the server socket should be closed. This means that the app will no longer be able to receive the subsequent incoming connections.

Currently I'm thinking of not closing the server socket and processing the incoming connections in a synchronous manner, so that the app will not try to accept a new connection until the previous one is processed and closed. What will happen if another peer tries to connect in the middle of such processing? Will it fail or just block until server is ready to accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says " BluetoothServerSocket can (and should) be discarded, unless you want to accept more connections." Since you want to accept more connections, then you should keep it.

Documentation also says the following about ServerSocket's accept method.
Accept is a blocking call. It will return when either a connection has been accepted or an exception has occurred. A connection is accepted only when a remote device has sent a connection request with a UUID matching the one registered with this listening server socket. When successful, accept() will return a connected BluetoothSocket.

Comment: I've tested my initial idea (everlasting server socket + synchronous processing). It seems to be working: incoming connections wait for their turn to get accepted. However, sometimes client sockets fail to connect (timeout?) and one of the devices has even got unbond somehow while waiting.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to create a separate server socket for each peer device.